# Calculating difference between min value and each row's value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table which has a person's id, name, and time (in milliseconds, stored as an `int`). For example:

```
| id  | name   | totalTime |
| --- | ------ | --------- |
| 1   | Bob    | 16280     |
| 2   | Andy   | 17210     |
| 3   | Bill   | 15320     |
| 4   | Matt   | 14440     |
| 5   | Steven | 17570     |
| 6   | Tom    | NULL      |
| 7   | Angus  | 17210     |
| 8   | Will   | NULL      |
| 9   | Jack   | 17410     |
| 10  | Alex   | 16830     |
```

Not necessarily all people have a time (thus the nulls).

I would like to have another two columns - one which shows the rank/position of each person, and another which shows the difference in time (milliseconds) between the best (i.e. minimum) time and each row's time.

I have managed to write a MySQL 8.x query which does the ranks:

```
SELECT id, name, totalTime, 

(CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL THEN RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY totalTime ) END) totalRank

FROM results

ORDER BY -totalRank DESC;
```

...and outputs this:

```
| id  | name   | totalTime | totalRank |
| --- | ------ | --------- | --------- |
| 4   | Matt   | 14440     | 1         |
| 3   | Bill   | 15320     | 2         |
| 1   | Bob    | 16280     | 3         |
| 10  | Alex   | 16830     | 4         |
| 2   | Andy   | 17210     | 5         |
| 7   | Angus  | 17210     | 5         |
| 9   | Jack   | 17410     | 7         |
| 5   | Steven | 17570     | 8         |
| 6   | Tom    | NULL      | NULL      |
| 8   | Will   | NULL      | NULL      |
```

...but have not been able to figure out the SQL to add another column with the time difference.

Below is an example of what I would like, but can't figure out how to do:

```
| id  | name   | totalTime | totalRank | difference |
| --- | ------ | --------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 4   | Matt   | 14440     | 1         | 0          |
| 3   | Bill   | 15320     | 2         | 880        |
| 1   | Bob    | 16280     | 3         | 1840       |
| 10  | Alex   | 16830     | 4         | 2390       |
| 2   | Andy   | 17210     | 5         | 2770       |
| 7   | Angus  | 17210     | 5         | 2770       |
| 9   | Jack   | 17410     | 7         | 2970       |
| 5   | Steven | 17570     | 8         | 3130       |
| 6   | Tom    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       |
| 8   | Will   | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       |
```

I have this available as a DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gQvSeij2EKSufYp9VjbDav/0

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to get the min `totalTime` and use it to calculate the `difference`:

```
WITH cte as (SELECT MIN(totalTime) minTotalTime FROM results)
SELECT id, name, totalTime, 
CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL 
  THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (
      CASE 
        WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END
  ) ORDER BY totalTime) 
END totalRank,
totalTime - (SELECT minTotalTime from cte) difference
FROM results
ORDER BY -totalRank DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gQvSeij2EKSufYp9VjbDav/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | totalTime | totalRank | difference |
| --- | ------ | --------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 4   | Matt   | 14440     | 1         | 0          |
| 3   | Bill   | 15320     | 2         | 880        |
| 1   | Bob    | 16280     | 3         | 1840       |
| 10  | Alex   | 16830     | 4         | 2390       |
| 2   | Andy   | 17210     | 5         | 2770       |
| 7   | Angus  | 17210     | 5         | 2770       |
| 9   | Jack   | 17410     | 7         | 2970       |
| 5   | Steven | 17570     | 8         | 3130       |
| 6   | Tom    |           |           |            |
| 8   | Will   |           |           |            |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            SELECT subtable.id,
                    subtable.NAME,
                    subtable.totalTime,                     
                    subtable.diff,

                    IIF(subtable.totalTime IS NULL,NULL,subtable.rowno) as bisi

                     FROM (
                    select *,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY totalTime desc) as rowno,
                            totalTime - 
                                        (
                                            select min(rst.totalTime) 
                                            from results rst) as diff
                        from results) subtable;
```

I would do this way in MS-SQL or alternatively in MYSQL

```
 SELECT subtable.id,
                    subtable.NAME,
                    subtable.totalTime,                     
                    subtable.diff,

                    IF (subtable.totalTime IS NULL,  NULL, subtable.rowno) as bisi

                     FROM (
                    select *,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY totalTime desc) as rowno,
                            totalTime - 
                                        (
                                            select min(rst.totalTime) 
                                            from results rst) as diff
                        from results) subtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add min() window function

```
SELECT id, name, totalTime, 

(CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL THEN RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY totalTime ) END) totalRank
,totaltime - min(totaltime) over() diff
FROM results
ORDER BY -totalRank DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Serg's answer is correct.  I would write it as:

```
SELECT id, name, totalTime, 
        (CASE WHEN totalTime IS NOT NULL
              THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (totalTime IS NULL) ORDER BY totalTime)
         END) as totalRank,
        totaltime - MIN(totaltime) OVER() as diff
FROM results
ORDER BY (totalTime IS NOT NULL) DESC, totalRank;
```

The differences are:

1. Simplifying the `PARTITION BY`.  You use `CASE`, but MySQL conveniently treats booleans as "real" values.
2. Expressing the `ORDER BY` in a more intuitive fashion.